# Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2 "install.build.tools" Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project

Tags: android

I am creating a new project in android and it keeps giving this error:

```
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2
"install.build.tools" Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project
```

but I have SDK Build Tools 27.x.x installed. I found an answer somewhere in Stackoverflow that i need to change it in build.gradle file (from 26 to 27), but the only build.gradle file I have is the one in which no such option is available. The file looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.  

buildscript {  

    repositories {  
        google()  
        jcenter()  
    }  
    dependencies {  
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'  


       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong  
        // in the individual module build.gradle files  
    }  
}  


allprojects {  
    repositories {  
        google()  
        jcenter()  
    }  
}  

task clean(type: Delete) {  
    delete rootProject.buildDir  
}
```

i am using android studio 3.0.1 Windows 10.
Ok I have found a way to view build.gradle file by manually installing the build tools v26.0.2. But now i am stuck in                                                               Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.

Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.
Required by:
    project :app

> No cached version of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1 available for offline mode.                                                                                                     Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.

Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Required by:
    project :app

> No cached version of junit:junit:4.12 available for offline mode.                                       Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.

Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.
Required by:
    project :app

> No cached version of com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1 available for offline mode.                                                                          now these are many errors i have to find manually one by one or someone could just tell me a better way.

Comment: you find the build.gradle in the App folder not in the project folder , check it.

Comment: Ok I have found a way to view build.gradle file by manually installing the build tools v26.0.2. But now i am stuck in

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/3637755/elyes                                                    I finally succeeded by removing these dependencies                                             dependencies {
    ...
//    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
now its running fine. I don't know why would i need those dependencies in the first place...

Comment: It's Android test library for your project.

Comment: you need to go build.gradle (module: app) in android studio